# run qwt example in Qt 5 on linux ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, qt, makefile, qwt

I cant figure out what I need to do for running example program which use Qwt library.

I download the file `qwt-6.1.2.tar.bz2` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwt/files/) as usual it goes to Download Direcory and I extract the file to this directory. I have now `qwt-6.1.2` directory in Downloads directory.

The Qt directory in my machine located in `/opt/Qt5.4.1/`

How I continue from here?

I try to run qmake:

`natile@natile-Precision-T1650:/opt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/bin$ sudo ./qmake /home/natile/Downloads/qwt-6.1.2/qwt.pro`

And after I ran make:

`natile@natile-Precision-T1650:/opt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/bin$ sudo make`

but I get an error:

`cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /opt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake /home/natile/Downloads/qwt-6.1.2/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile`

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/bin/src'
compiling /home/natile/qtcreator-projects/qwt/qwt-5.2/src/qwt_abstract_scale_draw.cpp
In file included from /home/natile/qtcreator-projects/qwt/qwt-5.2/src/qwt_abstract_scale_draw.cpp:19:0:
/home/natile/qtcreator-projects/qwt/qwt-5.2/src/qwt_scale_map.h:92:5: error: ‘QT_STATIC_CONST’ does not name a type
/home/natile/qtcreator-projects/qwt/qwt-5.2/src/qwt_scale_map.h:93:5: error: ‘QT_STATIC_CONST’ does not name a type
make[1]: *** [obj/qwt_abstract_scale_draw.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/bin/src'
make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I understand that I have to run qmake.

I get nothing in the installation URL: http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach works good for me:

```
cd /home/natile/Downloads/qwt-6.1.2/
mkdir build
/opt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake qwt.pro -o build/Makefile QWT_CONFIG="QwtExamples"
cd build
make
cd examples/bin
# Now you can launch any example, like:
./dials
```

Comment: it succeeded, thanks. How can i test it? i see examples that require add lines to the pro file like include or lib from /usr/local ??? I dont have qwt directory there. what is the next steps ?

Comment: Its Worked, I greatly appreciate some more help- What this flag do? I try to compile this in my arm compiler with no success. shuold i change it in the qmake or in make ? i have already the arm compiler and in my machine and it work well from my qtcreator, but i cant get it work in the command lines.

Comment: i ran this command but the file is still compiled to x86.  /opt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake QMAKE_CC=/opt/poky-qt/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ qwt.pro -o build/Makefile QWT_CONFIG="QwtExamples"